# Some tags need better names

Tags: discussion, tags

I think that some tags need better names, and want to start out, but will ask here first about opinions and ideas.

- Distribution tags should have names ending in *-distribution* (there might be exceptions like *chi-squared* which nothing can be done with). So *uniform-distribution*, *pareto-distribution*, ... For example, while we have both *exponential* and *exponential-distribution*, the shorter name invites misuse (rampant).
- *online* -> *online-algorithms* (the short name invites misunderstandings)
- *var* -> *vector-auto-regression*
- *ensemble* -> *ensemble-learning*
- *kruskal-wallis* -> *kruskal-wallis-test*  (and other similar)
- *mgf* -> *moment-generating-function*
- *irt* -> *item-response-theory*
- and certainly others ...

Comment: This is doable.  You make a synonym, merge the tags, then delete the merge.  Now the tag has been renamed.  If you thing the prior name led to the tag being used when it shouldn't, you may want to go through the threads & remove the tag where needed.

Comment: Why can nothing be done with *chi-squared*? I'd be very much in favor of adding *-distribution* at the end, to distinguish questions about the distribution from those that should have a suffix *-test*.

Comment: @Stephan Kolassa: I would too,  but there are 2.5k Qs to wade through ... doing 20 a day that is about 4 months ... so it is doable

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, if you don't get every last one, it's OK.  It doesn't have to be perfect. Do a search on `[chi-squared] distribution is:question` & switch the ones that need it & then change the rest to `[chi-squared-test]`.  Even if you got every last one, people will misuse the tags in the future, so there will always be the ebb & flow of inattentive users mistagging, & the occasional reader who stumbles across the thread editing it.

Comment: So as people are positive to this I will start out! Add ideas ...